# Dissecting a string value into separate words in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a system feeding information to my database into a table (`MESSAGE_COLLECT`) which has 3 columns;

```
INTRF_ID
INTRF_SOURCE
INTRF_MESSAGE
```

The `INTRF_ID` column contains a unique value, the `INTRF_SOURCE` contains an identifier that indicates from which system the interface is coming from and the `INTRF_MESSAGE` column contains a free format text message. Current issue I am facing is that there is a need to analyze the content of `INTRF_MESSAGE` as soon as it has been inserted and update another table with this.

Messages in `INTRF_MESSAGE` contain information a bit like a tweet, short messages with keywords indicated by hashtags. For example;

```
*Walking to the #meeting to check with #Rick*
```

or

```
*All, the latest #slidedeck about #contracts is uploaded to our #fileserver*
```

What I am looking for is a query (function) that will return all keywords in combination with `INTRF_ID` without the hashtag so I can loop this into a insert function to update a second table named `MESSAGE_COLLECT_KEYWORD_INDEX`.

For example the result for the first example (Walking to the #meeting to check with #Rick) should be;

```
INTRF_ID    KEYWORD
--------    ------
56326172    meeting
56326172    Rick
```

and the result set for the second example should be:

```
INTRF_ID    KEYWORD
--------    ------
76352517    slidedeck
76352517    contracts
76352517    fileserver
```

Any good pointers on how to tackle this while keeping in mind that the length of messages in `INTRF_MESSAGE` can be variable and also the number of hashtags with keywords. Also it is not always the case you have a single space between words.... a user could make a type and add two spaces between a word meaning this cannot be used as a unique delimiter between words...

Comment: Probably best to handle that logic at the application level, assuming one is available.

Comment: @Strawberry Agree with you that that would be the best option from a coding perspective however it is not an option due to the fact that I do not control the "feeding" application and only receive the information directly into the database. Only then I can act upon it,..... meaning,... the issue has to be resolved from within the database... that is what makes this a bit more tricky ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a database function and use regular expresions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/regexp.html